# pandas pivot_table, get index of certain row

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I created pivot table:

```
matrix_df = data.pivot_table(index = 'title', columns = 'userId', values = 'rating')
```

So, for each 'title' I have row of some numerical data.
I create 2d array out of this numerical data:

```
matrix = matrix_df.to_numpy()
```

Then  I did something with this data and find that row I need has index 32.
Now I want to check what is the title of row 32.
I can access this row from matrix_df:

```
matrix_df.iloc[32]
```

But how I can get the actual title?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since title seems to be your index, you can just extract the value for `index` at the row 32

```
matrix_df.index[32]
```